# I Am trying to change what table shows according to what is being written in the input field chars

Tags: arrays, angular, object, input, char

I Am trying to change a table view ,according to what is being written in the input field.
For example 
if i type in the input field , letter A,
i want the table to show all the objects in that array whose names begin with letter A.
after that , if i continue typing another letter, which is B
i want the table to show 
whose names begin with letter A and B.

I Am using angular 5 thought .

Just to confirm , i was able to do that , by doing several if statements, but this is not good , because lets assume the length of the input field that i want all the time to check is 20 characters, so it is not smart, to do 20 if statements ... that is why , i need a help in this issue actually.

Look at my code please .

```
    const tempArray = [];
    let desserts2;

  for (let i = 0 ; i < this.desserts.length; i++ ) {
    if ( state.charAt(this.counter) === 
this.desserts[i].name.charAt(this.counter) ) {
      tempArray.push(this.desserts[i]);
      desserts2 = tempArray;
      this.sortedData = desserts2.slice();
      this.showClearImage = true;
      this.placeholderText = '';
    }
  }
  tempArray.length = 0 ;
  for (let i = 0 ; i < this.desserts.length; i++ ) {
    if (
      state.charAt(this.counter + 1 ) === 
this.desserts[i].name.charAt(this.counter + 1 )  &&
      state.charAt(this.counter) === 
this.desserts[i].name.charAt(this.counter)
    ) {
      tempArray.push(this.desserts[i]);
      desserts2 = tempArray;
      this.sortedData = desserts2.slice();
      this.showClearImage = true;
      this.placeholderText = '';
    }
  }
  tempArray.length = 0 ;
  for (let i = 0 ; i < this.desserts.length; i++ ) {
    if (
      state.charAt(this.counter + 2 ) === 
this.desserts[i].name.charAt(this.counter + 2 ) &&
      state.charAt(this.counter + 1 ) === 
this.desserts[i].name.charAt(this.counter + 1 )  &&
      state.charAt(this.counter) === 
this.desserts[i].name.charAt(this.counter)
    ) {
      tempArray.push(this.desserts[i]);
      desserts2 = tempArray;
      this.sortedData = desserts2.slice();
      this.showClearImage = true;
      this.placeholderText = '';
    }
  }
  tempArray.length = 0 ;
  for (let i = 0 ; i < this.desserts.length; i++ ) {
    if (
      state.charAt(this.counter + 3 ) === 
this.desserts[i].name.charAt(this.counter + 3 ) &&
      state.charAt(this.counter + 2 ) === 
this.desserts[i].name.charAt(this.counter + 2 ) &&
      state.charAt(this.counter + 1 ) === 
this.desserts[i].name.charAt(this.counter + 1 )  &&
      state.charAt(this.counter) === 
this.desserts[i].name.charAt(this.counter)
    ) {
      tempArray.push(this.desserts[i]);
      desserts2 = tempArray;
      this.sortedData = desserts2.slice();
      this.showClearImage = true;
      this.placeholderText = '';
    }
  }
```